Category with 1 object and two morphisms
We have a category $\mathcal{C}$ with a single object $*$ and two morphisms: the identity $e$ and another morphism $\tau$.
We say that $\tau \circ \tau=e$. What I don't understand is how $\tau$ and $e$ are different. Because both functions do:

$\tau: * \to *$
$e: * \to *$

Since there is only 1 object in the category, a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ can only send this object to itself.
I can see that $\tau \circ \tau: * \to * \to * = * \to * = e$. But I don't understand how $\tau \neq e$? Because if we have $\tau=e$, then either the identity is not unique or we have two copies of the same morphism.

Edit: my question is basicually: how can the two arrows $e$ and $\tau$ be different if they are pointing from the same object to the same object?
To me, this seems like saying (given a set $Y=\{\{0\}\}$ and functions $f,g:Y\to Y$) that $f:\{0\} \mapsto \{0\}$, and $g:\{0\}\mapsto \{0\}$ and also saying $f\neq g$, which doesn't make sense. I suspect the problem is that I'm not thinking abstract enough and thinking too much in terms of functions (i.e. it's more like $Y\to Y$ than $\{0\}\mapsto \{0\}$).

My thinking was that a morphism is completely specified by where it "sends" every object in the category, analogous to how a function would be completely specified if you specify what it does with every element. Here is what I mean:
Suppose we have two sets: $S=\{0,1,2\}$ and $X=\{4,6,10\}$. Then if I specify a function $f: S \to X$ by where it sends the elements of the set:

$f: 0 \mapsto 4$, $f: 1 \mapsto 6$, $f: 2 \mapsto 10$

then $f$ is completely specified. That is, there is no "new" information we can learn that we can't deduce/ find out from this. If we also have a function $g$ which does exactly the same, then I would conclude $f=g$.

Context: This was introduced in an algebraic topology lecture where the lecturer breifly talked about category theory. This was one example of a category.
Any help to clear up my confusion would be greatly appreciated.

"My thinking was that a morphism is completely specified by where it sends every object in the category." This makes no sense. A morphism doesn't send objects anywhere. You're mixing up objects with elements of a set / object, but this latter notion doesn't make sense in a general category.

Maybe the following will help you see more clearly: Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the subcategory of $\mathrm{Set}$ with the single object ${1, 2}$ and morphisms given by its auto-bijections, of which there are two: the identity and the swap map $\tau\colon {1, 2} \to {1, 2}$ given by $\tau(1) = 2$ and $\tau(2) = 1$. Then $\mathcal{D}$ is isomorphic to your category $\mathcal{C}$, but for $\mathcal{D}$ you immediately see that the two morphisms aren't the same.

You are making a mistake by considering what is inside the objects.
While this may be relevant for concrete categories like Set where (informally) objects are sets and morphisms are functions this is not true for categories in general.
When defining Categories we don't care about what "really" are objects and morphisms.

If we started instead with a group with two elements ${e,\tau}$, would it be equally hard to see why $e\neq \tau$?  What you are discussing is "the same as" a group with two elements.

Also, there's another category with one object and two morphisms where $\tau\tau=\tau$.  It's a monoid but not a group.

Hmm... is it like how we can have two functions $f: X \to X$ and $g: X \to X$, but say we have $f: x \mapsto x^2$ and $g: x \mapsto 2x$. Then $f \neq g$ even though both f and g send $X \to X$? Is the problem just that I am "missing" one level of abstraction?

Yes. You're missing the important fact that in general, morphisms are not functions.

When considering "made up" categories like yours, it is useful to view them as algebraic objects themselves rather than collections of mathematical objects and morphisms between them. If you agree that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a group (hence a monoid) with exactly two elements $0 \neq 1$, then you should convince yourself that your category is the delooping of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

You must learn to think abstractly. A category is a collection of objects and morphisms with certain properties. The morphisms do not have to be functions and, in your case, are not. They are simply named arrows. In fact, you can have as many arrows as you want, even if there is only one object.


Because both functions do ...

Note that morphisms in a category are in general no functions in the sense of set theory. Anyway, a category is specified by its objects and its morphisms.
The category $\mathcal C$ is defined as follows:
It has a single object called  $*$. Thus it must have a single $\operatorname{hom}$-set $\operatorname{hom}(*,*)$. We define $\operatorname{hom}(*,*) = \{e, \tau\}$ with two distinct elements $e, \tau$. The names of these elements are irrelevant, we could also define $\operatorname{hom}(*,*) = \{1,-1\}$.
Composition is defined by $e \circ e = e$, $\tau \circ e = e \circ \tau =  \tau$ and $\tau \circ \tau = e$. Thus $e$ is the identity on the object $*$.
Both $e, \tau$ have the same domain and the same codomain, but they are different by definition.
Perhaps it is helpful to consider another example. Let $\mathcal D$ be defined as follows:
Its single object is the abelian group $\mathbb Z$. The set of morphisms $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ is the set of group automorphisms on $\mathbb Z$, i.e. $\operatorname{hom}(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z) = \{id_\mathbb Z,-id_\mathbb Z\}$. Composition of morphisms is defined as the ordinary composition of functions.
You will see that $\mathcal C$ is nothing else than $\mathcal D$ with the following renamings:

$* := \mathbb Z$.
$e := id_\mathbb Z, \tau := -id_\mathbb Z$.



My thinking was that a morphism is completely specified by where it sends every object in the category.

Morphisms don't send objects though. The relationships between objects and morphisms are only "domain" and "codomain."  Nothing here is mentioned about what a morphism does with "the inside" of an object, because nothing has been assumed about the insides of the objects.
The focus in category theory is purely on how the arrows relate objects to each other.
For example, a group, considered as a category, has only one object and potentially very many arrows.  They all have the same domain and codomain. But everything interesting about the group goes on in the arrows.
If it helps, there is a description of categories as "a multidigraph and its paths in subject to constraints."  (That's not an official term, it's just my recollection of the situation.) You can start with any digraph you like, and then generate all paths (sequences of edges in the graph) including the empty ones.  The set of edges does not allow composition, but paths can clearly be composed with concatenation.  Now, quite arbitrarily, one can impose constraints that say some paths happen to be equal.  This describes a category.  The paths suit the axioms for the arrows of a category.
For your example, we could consider the digraph with one node and one edge $\tau$.  When considering the paths in the digraph, we would have no license to say that any of the powers of $\tau$ are the same.  We would be looking at a picture of the infinite abelian cyclic group.  Once we add the constraint that the path $\tau^2=$empty path, then all such paths are equivalent to either the empty path or to the $\tau$ path.

But if I have one objects and two arrows from the object to itself, doesn't those arrows "relate" the object to itself in the same way?

@Vebjorn No. They express two potentially different outlooks on the object.

What you're saying is like asking "are all the elements of a group basically the same as the identity element?" What is interesting about the elements is how they combine with each other, and that's what is interesting about arrows.

Incidentally, that's why arrows usually have to be decorated with a label.  An arrow drawn between two objects alone does not tell you which arrow it is.  I note in your post you did not decorate you arrows with labels.
